# three.js - TubeGeometry + DecalGeometry on a segment of the tube

Tags: javascript, three.js, decal

I want to put a decal inside a segment of a tube geometry (in the backface).

The way I do is use TubeGeometry as the decal geometry.

This is what I have:
[image]

And this is what I want:
[image]
 *(bad drawing)*

Sample code:

```
//code
var tube = new THREE.TubeGeometry(pipelineSpline, 200, 20, 20, closed2);

tubeMesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(
       geometry, [
            material,       // a phong material
            materialInside // a material for the inside               
       ]);

scene.add(tubeMesh); 

var decalGeometry = new THREE.DecalGeometry(
      tubeMesh.children[0], 
      new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0),      //position
      new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0),      //direction
      new THREE.Vector3(10,10,10),   //dimensions
      new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0)       //check
    );
```

However this seems to apply a decal of the tube along all the backside geometry path. And I want it only on one part of the BackSide of the Tube on key positions.

How can I make a localized decal in a TubeGeometry using THREE.DecalGeometry? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use a `ShaderMaterial` for this, and define the positioning and opacity rules in the shader code and the various `uniform` (e.g., the new texture) and `parameter` (e.g., UV) values passed to it by THREE.js.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And cant it be done with using THREE.DecalGeometry https://github.com/spite/THREE.DecalGeometry? Best

Comment: That's not in the standard library :) A geo-heavy method like that is good for set-dressing, but will struggle if the decals are being placed dynamically (say, as explosion burns in a game). Only you know the context you need.

Comment: Thank you  @bjorke  They will be put at the start of the scene... like 10 along the pipe and then will be static

Comment: This question interests me as well, can't the decal be applied just to some faces of a mesh as an extra material with a texture map? Just thinking if there's an easier way than going through a custom shader

Comment: Hi @MacK If it works is great for me. I also thought of something along this lines: I only know the world coordinates of the decal, so I might need to do some automatic raycast by some way to find say the 4 left lateral faces of the tube and maybe use MeshFaceMaterial to put the texture there... I don't know if can apply a texture to cover a set of faces without the texture repeating itself for each face...